# Slider completely change ticks more than once

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, slider

I have a slider is binded to a DoubleCollection Ticks (via Ticks="{Binding Ticks}") which has a set of values. The Ticks collection eventually gets cleared and filled with completely different values. The problem is that after the refill the slider still moves by the old ticks even though the values in the collection are already different.

How does one workaround this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the tick collection is not dependant of the min and max values.

The slider value depends on Min and Max value, ticks are only "decoration".

The above example should work.

Basically, when changing the ticks collection, I change the `Minimum` and `Maximum` bound values to fit the min and max of the tick collection.

C# part :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _value;
    private double _minimum;
    private double _maximum;
    private DoubleCollection _tickCollection;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        TickCollection = new DoubleCollection();
        for (double i = 0.0; i < 5.0; i+=0.5)
        {
            TickCollection.Add(i);
        }
        Minimum = 0.0;
        Maximum = 5.0;
        Value = 2.3;

    }

    public double Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public double Minimum
    {
        get { return _minimum; }
        set { _minimum = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public double Maximum
    {
        get { return _maximum; }
        set { _maximum = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public DoubleCollection TickCollection
    {
        get { return _tickCollection; }
        set
        {
            _tickCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TickCollection = new DoubleCollection();
        for (double i = 5.0; i < 10.0; i += 1.0)
        {
            TickCollection.Add(i);
        }
        Minimum = 5.0;
        Maximum = 10.0;
        Value = 2.3;

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

XAML Conterpart:

```
    <Grid>
    <Slider x:Name="mySlider" Width="400" Height="40" Ticks="{Binding TickCollection}"
            TickPlacement="TopLeft"
            Minimum="{Binding Minimum}"
            Maximum="{Binding Maximum}"
            Value="{Binding Value,Mode=TwoWay}"
            ></Slider>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
    <Button Content="Change Ticks" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,60" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I actually had minimum and maximum values binded but i just forgot to notify them on update